# cannot retrieve token price

Tags: solidity, tokens, javascript, truffle-contract

i am trying to code a decentralized application and what i am trying to do right now is to get the token price of 1000000000000000 and display it. but when i try to get token price i keep getting 0. im using metamask

```
App = {
 web3Provider: null,
 contracts: {},
 account: '0x0',
 loading: false,
 tokenPrice: 1000000000000000,

 App.contracts.DappTokenSale.deployed().then((instance) => {
  dappTokenSaleInstance = instance;
  return dappTokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
}).then((tokenPrice) => {
  App.tokenPrice = tokenPrice;
  $('.token-price').html(web3.fromWei(App.tokenPrice, "ether").toNumber());
}
```

console log results of tokenprice Object { s: 1, e: 0, c: (1) […] }

this is the the code that i am following, it worked for him but how come it doesnt work for me.
https://github.com/dappuniversity/token_sale

Comment: Please `console.log(web3.fromWei(App.tokenPrice, "ether"))` and share the result.

Comment: this is the result Object { s: 1, e: 0, c: (1) […] } without toNumber(), 0 with toNumber()

Comment: Never use `toNumber` on a `BigNumber` object, unless you are certain that it represents a value smaller than 2 ^ 53 (Javascript's max safe integer). Please change `toNumber` to `toFixed()` and share the result.

Comment: toFixed() result token price:  0, thank you for sharing to me yet i still get same result

Comment: BTW, for the same reason above (max safe integer), change `tokenPrice: 1000000000000000` to `tokenPrice: "1000000000000000"` or to `tokenPrice: new BigNumber("1000000000000000")`.

Comment: still the same 0 on "1000000" and an error on BigNumber("100000") uncaught ReferenceError: BigNumber is not defined

Comment: Well you need to `require("bignumber.js")` you know!

Answer (score 0):

i got it solved, just reset the migration and incase if u have ur main as truffle.js in package.JSON change it to truffle-config.js(only if u had did the network configrations initially in that file). !reset migration every time u reopen ganache.